# How can we send a request to the sharepoint search service?

Tags: search, service, request, sharepoint-2013

can somebody explain to me how can we send a request to the sharepoint search service?
i am going to start developping on sharepoint 2013.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use rest api then you can download the following search tool
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/11/10/sharepoint-2013-search-query-tool-released-on-codeplex.aspx

you put the values and you will get the rest api query.
To use search client object model follow the below link

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/09/10/how-to-query-search-with-the-sharepoint-2013-client-object-model.aspx

Hope it helps